# Mockk and Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> List<Array<Any>> but (Mutable)List<Array<(out) Any!>!>! was expected

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I'm writing unit tests in Kotlin with Mockk and I'm running into this error: `Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> MutableList<Array<out Any>> but (Mutable)List<Array<(out) Any!>!>! was expected`

The interface I'm trying to mock is written in Java with a return type of `List<Object[]>`. I cannot figure out how to mock a response to this method, I've tried a number of different combinations, nothing seems to work.

I was able to duplicate this error with a simple example below. Any ideas??

Here is the Java interface:

```
public interface TestInterface {
    List<Object[]> test();
}
```

And the Unit test:

```
class KotlinTest {

    private val mockTest = mockkClass(TestInterface::class)

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val array : Array<out Any> = arrayOf("string", 1)
        val list = mutableListOf(array)

        every {
            mockTest.test()
        } returns {
            list
        }
    }
}
```

The unit test fails to compile with the `Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> MutableList<Array<out Any>> but (Mutable)List<Array<(out) Any!>!>! was expected` error.

Comment: try removing curly braces from around the `list` after `returns` keyword

Comment: thanks .. I've been working on this for like an hour and just came to the same conclusion. I tripped myself up because I've been using "answers" for most of my mocks, which works with the curly braces. argh.